# Alternating power series $\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, theta-functions

Suppose that $f(x):=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^ke^{-(2k+1)^2x}$ has a holomorphic continuation to a neighborhood of $0$, that is, $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ for $x> 0$ small. I want to know the value of $a_1$. Let $z=e^{-x}$, $g(z):=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2}$; then, formally, $g'(1)$ is what we want to compute. Note that $1$ is on the circle of convergence of $g$ so differentiating term-wise is not guaranteed.

Comment: Just differentiate $f(x)$ element-wise, then input $x = 0$ (then add all the formal "what I did was ok, because..."). As mathoverflow deals with research level questions, you might want to try at math.SE. However, note that also there you will need your own approaches.

Comment: @Bemte: I am afraid you may have judged this question too quickly.

Comment: I don't see how as the result is divergent in doing so.

Comment: I would compute $f'(0) = \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^{k+1}(2k+1)^2$ and therefore conclude that yes, $f'(0)$ does not exist. Ok, I thought it existed first, so I might have been a little to fast in judging, yes. But still, you should explain how you come to assume that $f$ even has an expansion in the neighborhood of $0$, as this would give $a_1$ to be a non-existing/non-converging (?) number?

Comment: @Menglin: a formal expansion of the exponentials suggests that $a_n = (-1)^n n!^{-1} L(-n,\chi)$ where $\chi $ is the nontrivial Dirichlet characer of odrer $4$. One can rigorously prove an asymptotic expansion $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n + o(x^N)$, with the $a_n$ as above, by writing the exponentials as an inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)$, and by moving the line of integration to the left using the residue theorem.

Comment: (continued)  I should have written $a_n = (-1)^n n!^{-1} L(-2n, \chi)$ instead. Note that $L(-2n,\chi)$ is equal to half of the $(2n)-$th Euler number $E_{2n}$ (which is $= (2n)! \times$ coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the hyperbolic sechant $\mathrm{sech}(x)$). in particular $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Calculations in the paper "[A $q$-series identity and the arithmetic of Hurwitz zeta functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-03/S0002-9939-02-06649-2/)" by Coogan and Ono (PAMS **131** (2003), 719-724) confirm (I believe) calculations by @js21 in the comments. They have (see their (1.3))
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant0}(-1)^ke^{-(2k+1)^2x}=\frac {e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(e^{-2x};e^{-4x})_ne^{-2nx}}{(-e^{-6x};e^{-4x})_n}=\frac12+\frac12x+\frac54x^2+...=\sum_{n\geqslant0}L(\chi_{-1},-2n)\frac{(-x)^n}{n!},
$$
exactly as in the above comment.

Comment: Btw they also give an alternative expression for the same:
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant0}\left(\zeta(-2n,\frac14)-\zeta(-2n,\frac34)\right)\frac{(-16x)^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: @js21 ...so I believe you should make an answer :)

Comment: @Menglin: I've made some stylistic changes, in an attempt to state more clearly what I think you wanted to ask (maybe it's just me, but I found your earlier version mildly confusing). Feel free to go back to your version of course if you don't like this.

Comment: @ChristianRemling your edit directed my attention to one circumstance - it might well be that $f$ is not actually defined in a neighborhood of $0$ at all and the sought value should be understood as the limiting value as $x$ tends to $0$ along the real axis. It is not even clear to me whether one would obtain the same value if $x$ goes to $0$ tangentially - say, $x=t^2+it$ and $t\to0$ (from the positive direction). The latter limit might not even exist.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Indeed. I also made (while editing) the very similar observation that "supposing" that $f(x)$ has a holomorphic continuation to a neighborhood of zero won't help if that is actually false.

Comment: @Christian Remling: Thanks for the update. Perhaps the possibility of analytic continuation should also be included as part of the question. I guess that's also what misled Bemte before.

Comment: Tried to make some plots, looks like it cannot be continued beyond $\operatorname{Re}(x)>0$

Comment: @js21: A question about the convergence of your series: is the expansion only asymptotic or convergent in some sense near 0?

Comment: Only asymptotic. Check the growth of the coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

We can indeed prove, as already suspected by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, that
$g(z)=\sum (-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2}$ cannot be holomorphically continued past $z=1$. In fact, every point on $|z|=1$ is singular. This is a consequence of the following rather general version of the classical results on lacunary power series:

> Theorem: Suppose that $a_n$ is bounded. Suppose further that there exists a sequence $n_j\to\infty$ such that: (1) $|a_{n_j}|\ge\delta>0$; (2) $a_{n_j-k}\to 0$ as $j\to\infty$ for every fixed $k\ge 1$.
>   Then $\sum a_n z^n$ cannot be holomorphically continued to any open set larger than the unit disk.

(Note that $R=1$ under these assumptions.)

Of course, this applies to our power series, with $n_j=(2j+1)^2$.

A very elegant proof of the Theorem was recently given by Breuer-Simon. See reference 328 [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/simon/biblio.html), Theorem 1.6 of the paper.

Comment: From numerical experiments, $g$ seems to have well-defined radial limits at all roots of unity. It tends to infinity very quickly along radii to $e^{2\pi i\frac pq}$ with both $p$ and $q$ odd, and to certain finite limit when only one of $p$, $q$ is even.

Comment: In fact, from the Coogan-Ono paper I linked in a comment to the question, one has$$g(z)=\frac{z}{1+z^2}+\frac{z^3 \left(1-z^2\right)}{\left(1+z^2\right) \left(1+z^6\right)}+\frac{z^5 \left(1-z^2\right) \left(1-z^6\right)}{\left(1+z^2\right)
   \left(1+z^6\right) \left(1+z^{10}\right)}+\frac{z^7 \left(1-z^2\right) \left(1-z^6\right) \left(1-z^{10}\right)}{\left(1+z^2\right) \left(1+z^6\right)
   \left(1+z^{10}\right) \left(1+z^{14}\right)}+...$$

Comment: and similarly to what Zagier does in his paper "[Vassiliev invariants and a strange identity related to
the Dedekind eta-function](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1016/S0040-9383(00)00005-7/fulltext.pdf)", I believe one can prove that these radial limits coincide with the result of substituting roots of unity in the above series (on roots of unity this actually terminates, giving infinity on "odd-odd" roots of unity and a well-defined explicit expression on all other roots of unity)

Comment: Hey, can I ask how $|a_{n_j-k}|\rightarrow 0$ in our case? I thought $a_{i}=(-1)^{i}$. Not sure what I am missing at here...

Comment: @Bombyxmori: $a_n=0$ unless $n=(2j+1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an answer, this is (I believe) an evidence of analyticity boundary along the imaginary axis. Here are plots for the logarithm of the absolute value of $f(x)$:

[image]

[image]

(can be enlarged by clicking twice)

Answer (score 1):

(not finished) We have
$$
g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{(4k+1)^2}-z^{(4k+3)^2}=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(z^{(4k+1)^2}+\dots+z^{(4k+3)^2-1}\right)=\\
=\frac12+(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(z^{(4k+1)^2}+\dots+z^{(4k+3)^2-1}\right)-\frac12\left(z^{(4k+1)^2-1}+\dots+z^{(4k+5)^2-2}\right).
$$
Thus $(2g(z)-1)/(1-z)$ evaluated at $z=1$ (that is, $2g'(1)$) is an Abel sum of the corresponding alternating series, which, I guess, converges by certain multiple Cezaro.